# Three positive numbers whose sum is 100 and whose product is a maximum

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, word-problem

> Find the three positive numbers whose sum is $100$ and whose product is maximal.

We did this problem in class today and I'm having difficult understand a certain part of the solution.

$$\begin{align}x+y+z& =100 \\
xyz& = xy(100-x-y)
\end{align}$$

After this point I understand everything ($\nabla f)$ etc.. But it's just the line $$xyz=xy(100-x-y)$$

I don't see where he got this from. Could someone shed some light on how he knew this is the equation he needed.

Comment: You want to maximize $xyz$ and, according to the first equation, $z=100-x-y$.

Comment: Just take the equation $x+y+z=100$ and subtract x+y on both sides to get $z=100-x-y$ This was plugged in for $z$

Comment: Let $y=ax$ and $z=bx$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks guys. I should have seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x+y+z=100\implies z=100-x-y$$

which means $$xyz=xy\times z=xy(100-x-y)$$